# Java: Jackson String to Json - Can not deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapper

Getting straight to it...

I have a method that returns a string (see example string below) - essentially, I make a HTTP GET Request to a URL and the response is the string below...

```
{
  "total": 30,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "parent": "parentA",
      "children": "childB, childC, childD"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parent": "parentE",
      "children": "childF, childG, childH"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "parent": "parentI",
      "children": "childJ, childK, childL"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "parent": "parentM",
      "children": "childN, childO"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "parent": "parentP",
      "children": "childQ, childR, childS, childT"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "parent": "parentU",
      "children": "childV, childW, childX"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "parent": "parentY",
      "children": "childZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then assign this string to a variable, then map it to my model...

```
String strRel = <JSON OBJECT FROM ABOVE>
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyModel obj = mapper.readValue(strRel, MyModel.class);
```

However, when I run my code, it, unfortunately, returns the following error...

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.my.models.MyModel out of START_ARRAY token
```

Ultimately, I know what is causing the error, it's the Array of Objects, "rows"...but I am not sure how to fix it. Obviously, I cannot change the schema of the string/object coming back to me.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
MyModel

```
public class MyModel {
    public MyModel() {}

    private int total;
    private ModelRows rows;

    public int getTotal() { return total; }
    public ModelRows getRows() { return rows; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
ModelRows

```
public class ModelRows {
    public ModelRows() {}

    private int id;
    private String parent;
    private String children;

    public int getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getParent() { return parent; }

    public void setParent(String parent) { this.parent = parent; }

    public String getChildren() { return children; }

    public void setChildren(String children) { this.children = children; }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `MyModel`

Comment: The `rows` need to be a collection in your model

Comment: @Mubin...there you go

Comment: @Pete, can you post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit...

Comment: @DidierJeanCharles no need! glad that the comment helped you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made below changes in your MyModel class

```
public class MyModel {
    public MyModel() {}

    private int total;
    private List<ModelRows> rows;

    public int getTotal() { return total; }
    public List<ModelRows> getRows() { return rows; }
}
```